# Trying to create a pivot table in a newly created worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

So I am trying to create a pivot table. The code that I have now works fine. However, what I am trying to do now is create a new worksheet in my workbook and have the pivot table be made in the new worksheet. This code works fine when the worksheet is already there, however, once I add in the new line of code to create the new worksheet, it fails me.

```
Sub ISM_Pivot()
'-------------------------------------------------

'    Step 1: Create a new worksheet for pivot table

'--------------------------------------------------

Dim WSD2 As Worksheet

 Set WSD2 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Add(After:= _
           Worksheets(Worksheets.Count))
   WSD2.Name = "POS Info"


'--------------------------------------------------

'        Step 2: Create the pivot table

'--------------------------------------------------

Dim WSD As Worksheet
Dim PTCache As PivotCache
Dim PT As PivotTable
Dim PRange As Range
Dim FinalRow As Long
Dim FinalCol As Long
Dim StartPT As String
Set WSD = Worksheets("aggregateData")


' Select the data for pivot table

FinalRow = WSD.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
FinalCol = WSD.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
Set PRange = WSD.Cells(2, 1).Resize(FinalRow, FinalCol)
Set PTCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=PRange, Version:=xlPivotTableVersion14)

'Where do I want the pivot table to start

StartPT = WSD2.Range("A1").Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1)


'Begin to Create the Pivot Table

Set PT = PTCache.CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:=StartPT, TableName:="POS Data")
```

The last line of code is where it fails me. I get an application defined or object-defined error.

Any help would be great,

Thanks,

Griffin

Comment: Try adding `Set WSD2 = Worksheets("POS Info")` before `StartPT = WSD2.Range("A1").Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1)`

Comment: Worked. Thanks so much. My only real question is why did this work?

Comment: To be honest, I'm not entirely sure... And I just tried your code above that you originally had, and it worked fine - which leads me to believe that you may not even need that extra line of code at all! I thought it was because of how you did `Set = WSD2` up top, but I think that actually worked fine.

Comment: makes no sense to me either .... you could have used `StartPT = WSD.Range("A1").Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1)` because all you are doing is converting `"A1"` to `"R1C1"` .... makes no difference which worksheet you are using